# When adding this servlet code server getting stopped

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have a login form program. So there is a JSP and servlet page. While creating the servlet code the tomcat server is getting stopped.

While there is only the specific JSP page server is working. But when these codes have been added, its getting stopped.

```
@WebServlet("/validateLogin")
public class validateLogin extends HttpServlet {

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        try {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        String username = request.getParameter("Username");
        String password = request.getParameter("Password");

        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("userData.xlsx"));
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {

            // Next row.
            Row row = rowIterator.next();

            // Get column records.
            Cell column1 = row.getCell(0);
            Cell column2 = row.getCell(1);

            // Read records.
            if (column1 != null && column2 != null) {

                String recordUsername = ""; 
                String recordPassword  = "";

                if (column1.getCellType().toString().contains("STRING")) {
                    recordUsername = column1.getStringCellValue();
                } else if (column1.getCellType().toString().contains("NUMERIC")) {
                    recordUsername = Integer.toString((int)column1.getNumericCellValue());
                }

                if (column2.getCellType().toString().contains("STRING")) {
                    recordPassword = column2.getStringCellValue();
                } else if (column2.getCellType().toString().contains("NUMERIC")) {
                    recordPassword = Integer.toString((int)column2.getNumericCellValue());
                }


                if (username.equals(recordUsername) && password.equals(recordPassword)) {

                    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("logged.jsp");
                    rd.forward(request, response);
                } else {
                    out.print("Invalid");
                    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("viewLogin.jsp");
                    rd.include(request, response);                      
               }    
            }
            out.close();
        }
        }catch(Exception e) {

        }
    }    

    //protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //doGet(request, response);
//  }

}
```

I need to get values from JSP page and validate it and then move to another JSP page.

Comment: is getting stopped? do you get an error? Do you also understand why hiding exceptions won't really help you find errors in your code?

Comment: No error showing in the code. After this servlet page is added then server won't start.

Comment: codes never show errors. logs do. And, in your case, if the code does run, if an error occurs, you'll never know which, because you hide them.

Comment: Could you please make it clear. I'm a beginner in this area.

Comment: Probably, you are getting an exception, but you are not doing anything about it.
At the very least print the exception to stdout, and look in the TomCat ogs

Comment: @jr593 that's not what he describes. He states the server won't even start. He should check his Tomcat Logs.

Comment: can you show us error logs,stackTraces and your web.xml file ?

Comment: Instead of web.xml file im using web servlet annottation